# Jquery prototype conflict with new function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, prototype

I'm trying to make a complementary library to jQuery but not jQuery plugin, nor jQuery extension:

First Function:

```
function w(id) {
    return $(id);
     }
```

It works as jQuery plugin:

```
$.prototype.test = function(){
        console.log("testing");
        }
w("div").test(); // test
```

What I want is this, as a prototype function of w(), but doesn't works:

```
w.prototype.test = function(){
        console.log("testing");
        }
w("div").test(); // test
```

Thanks,

.........................................

It works with:

```
w.prototype = jQuery.prototype;
```

Thanks SLaks!

But when it does, doesn't works with:

```
w.prototype = {
    test: function(){
        console.log("testing");
    }}
```

.......................

Now it's works;

```
function w(id) {
    return $(id);
     }

w.prototype = jQuery.prototype;

w.prototype.extend({
    test:function(){
        console.log("testing");
        }
});
```

Thanks for help!!!

Comment: Why not using jQuery?

Comment: because the result from `w("div")` is a jQuery object, not an instance of `w`

Comment: Your function `w` must not return an object, and must be called with `new`, if you want its own prototype to take effect.

Comment: What exactly do you mean "a library complementary to jQuery"? What is it supposed to do, why do you think does a jQuery plugin not suit? Maybe you want to inherit from jQuery? Or put a wrapper class around it?

Comment: It's a library that use jQuery but wih other aims

Comment: You really seem to be looking for just `var w = $;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want

```
w.prototype = jQuery.prototype;
```

Comment: Not sure whether he does. Can you please explain the pitfall of this solution?

Comment: function w(id) {
 return $(id);
  }

w.prototype = jQuery.prototype;

w.prototype.extend({
 test:function(){
        console.log("testing");
        }
});